# Abort call in SIGABRT Signal function in Linux

Tags: linux, signals

I have the same signal handler function for SIGABRT and SIGSEGV signals. The signal handler function prints some logs and then calls abort. Now when a segmentation fault occurs the signal handler displays the messages and calls abort function. The abort function raises the SIGABRT signal which results in signal handler function call and abort is called again. This recursive call causes the core dump file to be huge.
I fixed this by including a static variable in the function handler to ensure abort is called only once. Is there a better way to handle this ?. Could someone please suggest?.

Note: This problem does not exist in AIX. The abort function from the SIGABRT signal handler does raise the SIGABRT signal again.

Comment: What function are you using to set the signal handler? Is it `signal` or `sigaction` ?

Comment: Yes, most likely the reason is `signal`'s platform-dependent behaviour. Use another `signal` to unset the handler before `abort`